# Find a maximum complex function $ \max_{z \in {\mathbb C},|z| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}} \left|1-\frac{\sin z}{z}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am  trying to find the following maximum, whose existence is justified by the compactness of the close ball $\Delta$  of $\mathbb C$  and continuity of the function  $f:z \mapsto \left|1-\frac{\sin z}{z}\right|$ from $\mathbb C$   to  $\mathbb C$

$$\large { \displaystyle \max_{z \in {\mathbb C},|z| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}} \left|1-\frac{\sin z}{z}\right|}$$

any suggestions please?

Comment: Where does an analytic function achieve its max?

Comment: Hint: check the boundary points as Mhenni intimates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Maximum Modulus principle, we know that, for $r>0$ we have
$$
M(r)=\max_{|z|\leq r}\left\vert1-\frac{\sin z}{z}\right\vert
=\max_{|z|= r}\left\vert1-\frac{\sin z}{z}\right\vert
=\frac{1}{r}\max_{\theta\in\Bbb{R}}\left\vert re^{i\theta}-\sin(re^{i\theta})\right\vert
$$
Now, for $z\in\Bbb{C}$ we have
$$
\sin z-z=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} z^{2n+1}
$$
So, for every $\theta\in \Bbb{R}$  we have
$$
\vert\sin(re^{i\theta})-re^{i\theta}\vert\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)!} r^{2n+1}=\sinh(r)-r
$$
with eaulity if $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus
$$
\max_{\theta\in\Bbb{R}}\left\vert re^{i\theta}-\sin(re^{i\theta})\right\vert
=\sinh(r)-r$$
and consequently, for every $r>0$ we have
$$
M(r)=\max_{|z|\leq r}\left\vert1-\frac{\sin z}{z}\right\vert
=\frac{\sinh r}{r}-1.
$$
In particular, $M(\frac{\pi}{4})=\dfrac{4\sinh(\pi/4)}{\pi}-1\approx 0.106026$.$\qquad\square$